# If condition in a line in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement

```
<li><a href="/Law/GetAllLaw?type=@(ViewData["type"]!=null?Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["type"]))><i class="icon-list-ul"></i>My List</a></li>
```

I want to check 
if

```
ViewData["type"]
```

is not null

```
then convert to int 32
```

otherwise do not do anything.**

I tried to write if condition in one line however i could not write correctly.

Where i miss exactly in syntax ?
Thanks.

Comment: You`ve missed the last part of a ternary operator: ":".

Comment: And what do you want to send as an argument if there is no ViewData["type"]? Should it be 0 or maybe it is better to skip the whole "type" argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want 0 in else part try,

```
@(ViewData["type"]!=null?Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["type"]):0)
```

you are missing `:` in a condition (ternary operator)

Comment: you'll get an error about `int` and `string` not being the same type

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in `ViewDate["type"]` is an `int` or `null`, you could try this:

```
<li><a href="/Law/GetAllLaw?type=@(ViewData["type"] !=null ? Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["type"]) : (int?)null)><i class="icon-list-ul"></i>My List</a></li>
```

Otherwise it would be better to test if it's an parseable integer first. 
Then you could try:

```
int test;

@(int.TryParse(ViewDate["type"], out test) ? test.ToString() : "")
```